# Это неполное предложение?

Tags: синтаксис

Допустим, у нас есть следующие предложения.

> Если отклонят — уберу. Так-то ты верно рассуждаешь, но вдруг...

Меня интересует всё, что находится после союза ***но***. Второе предложение является сложным, а вторая часть неполная? Что там подразумевается? У меня есть предположение, что, если восстановить все члены, получается следующее:

> Если отклонят — уберу. Так-то ты верно рассуждаешь, но вдруг не отклонят...

Прошу рассудить.

Comment: Всё что угодно может следовать за "вдруг...", хорошо бы контекста побольше.

Comment: Вам это ничего не даст, поверьте. Здесь речь идет о том, примут ли такой-то ли перевод или нет.

Comment: Ну, конечно, Вам виднее.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Неполным это предложение быть не может. В неполных предложениях бывает пропущен один из членов, который восстанавливается из ближайшего контекста. Неполные предложения всегда являются завершенные и в смысловом и интонационным плане. Ср.: Сюда поставьте чайник, а сюда - самовар. В этом предложении ясно, что на месте тире мыслится сказуемое "поставьте."В вашем же примере не то что пропущен какой важный член, многоточие передает недосказанность мысли. После союза "но" стоит целое предложение.  ***Но вдруг не отклонят...*** - это новое неопределенно-личное предложение, а не сказуемое, восстанавливаемое из предыдущего контекста.

Comment: _Серж: Но вдруг не отклонят... - это новое **безличное** предложение..._ === **Безличное?**

Comment: Хотел написать: неопределенно -личные. спутал.